# Modal Popup scrolls the background to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have updated the previous issue and now this is the new issue I've encountered.

On http://www.christianluneborg.com website. Click on 'Website' link and then click on the 'Pure Network' image. You will notice the modal pops up and the background of the page scrolls back up to the home page. How do I stop that? It needs to stay on the 'Website' section of the page.

HTML -

```
<div class="image-wrap">
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open();"><img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="Pure Network"></a>
</div>
```

Modal -

```
<div id="Modal-Pure">
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_close();"><img src="img/website151.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
```

CSS -

```
#fade {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.4;
    opacity:.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
#Modal-Pure {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 836px;
    height: 636px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -100px;                 
    background: #000;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Javascript -

```
<script>
    window.document.onkeydown = function (e)
{
    if (!e){
    e = event;
}
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
    lightbox_close();
    }
}
function lightbox_open(){
    document.getElementById('Modal-Pure').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';  
}
function lightbox_close(){
    document.getElementById('Modal-Pure').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of triggering the modal using data-attributes, do it [using JavaScript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods).

```js
var myModal = $('#myModal');

$('img').click(function(){
   myModal.find('img').attr('src', this.dataset.src);
   myModal.modal('show');
});
```

```css
#myModal img {
   max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/26/10/33/stone-goat-2175189__340.jpg" data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/26/10/33/stone-goat-2175189_960_720.jpg" width="100" alt="goat">

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/17/04/07/beautiful-2150881__340.jpg" data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/17/04/07/beautiful-2150881_960_720.jpg" width="150" alt="beauty">

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Side-remark: `id` attribute should not be a number. Better to use data-attribute e.g. `data-id` to store the number. If you need to access it in the JS code, you would do `this.dataset.id`.

Comment: Thank you so much!, but when you click on these pictures it pops up the same image. I need it in a different image on the modal popup

Comment: You mean you want to pop up their full-sized image? In my last edit, I mentioned you can use data-attributes to store extra information. For example, you can add to each image `data-src` attribute to store the full-sized image path. Then in your JS code, simply replace `this.src` with `this.dataset.src`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I added a line of JS to stop background going to the top page when modal pops up.

```
document.body.style.overflow='hidden';
```

And added a line to enable the scrolling after hitting close link.

```
document.body.style.overflowY='visible';
```